# Create a column in a table view with a value based on a group of rows in another table

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to create a table view and include a new column that is based on values from another table.

Many rows of table B belong to one row of table A.

Table B has a `status` column (with values like `active`, `completed`, etc) and a foreign key (for table A).

In the new table view (for A) I want to create an `active` column (`true` / `false`) that is based on any related rows in table B having a `status` value of `active` and a matching foreign key.

Comment: could you post sample data? what is the current, what is the expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is just about checking if the value exists, then this should do the job

```
select  A.c1, 
        A.c2, 
        -- other columns from A
        case when exists (select 1 from B_Table B where A.FK = B.FK and B.status = 'active') 
            then 'true'
            else 'false'
        end as Active
from A_Table B
```

Comment: Almost, the subquery can return more than one row using…

```
select table_a.name, id, 
  case (select table_b.status from table_b where table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id) 
    when 'active' then 'true' else 'false'
  end as active
from table_a;
```

Comment: You just want the value true if active exist ? or you have other condition to select just one line?

Comment: yeah I think this may work:
```
SELECT table_a.name, id,
  CASE WHEN exists (SELECT table_b.status FROM table_b WHERE table_a.id = table_b.table_a_id AND table_b.status = 'active')
    THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
  END as active
FROM table_a;
```